# What is the size of a derived class if a base class has no members?

Tags: c++, generics, inheritance, sizeof, empty-class

Consider the following inheritance:

```
class Base {
protected:
  Base() { }
public:
  double Multiply(double x);
};

class Derived : public Base {
  double _value;
public:
  Derived(double init) : _value(init) { }
  double Multiply(double x) { return x*_value; }
};
```

This code piece is to be used in templated codebase. Polymorphism is not an option because it adds VTable pointer thus doubles the memory consumption.

However, I suspect that because of C++ requirement for objects to have size at least 1 byte, the size of `Derived` would become 9 bytes and, consequently, because of padding/alignment it will further become 16 bytes.

So is there a way in C++ to keep the size of `Derived` equal to the size of `double` (usually 8 bytes) ?
What does the standard say about the size of `Derived`?
Particularly, how does MSVC++ behave in this case?

Comment: @AndyG, I wouldn't like to `pack(1)`, because although I will save memory by making `Derived` 9 bytes long, I'll get huge penalty for unaligned access to `double` values, and I'll lose the possibility to use AVX2 efficiently.

Comment: Alternatively, you can force it with C++11 (forehead slap that I forgot about this) with [`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)

Comment: You can check yourself in MSVC. Try `constexpr auto test = sizeof(Derived);`. Intellisense should be able to provide you with the value of `test`, you don't even need to compile.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo

Comment: It will already be 8 bytes probably - but do check - this is due to the *empty baseclass optimization*. look it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called *Empty base optimization*, it is defined in standard as following:

> 1.8 The C ++ object model [intro.object]
>
> 7
>   Unless it is a bit-field (9.2.4), a most derived object shall have a nonzero size and shall occupy one or more bytes of storage. Base class subobjects may have zero size. An object of trivially copyable or standard-layout type (3.9) shall occupy contiguous bytes of storage.
>
> 8
>   Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address
>   of the first byte it occupies. Two objects a and b with overlapping lifetimes that are not bit-fields may have
>   the same address if one is nested within the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and
>   they are of different types; otherwise, they have distinct addresses.

In your example inheriting `Base` class does not affect the size of the `Derived` class. However MSVC++ performs such optimization only for a first empty base class so inheriting from addition empty base classes will lead to growth of `Derived` class size. I believe this has been a point of critisim towards MSVC++ for a long time, as many other compilers don't have this issue. This can be really troublesome if you have a lot of small auxiliary classes. As a workaround a deriving template base class could be used to convert multiple inheritance into a chain of single inheritance:

```c++
class Base1
{};

template< typename TBase > class Base2: public TBase
{};

template< typename TBase > class Base3: public TBase
{};

class Derived: public Base3< Base2< Base1 > >
{};
```

[MS Connect bug page](http://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/771716/empty-base-optimization-broken). It looks like they aren't aiming to fix it after all.